# Is $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ equal to $\mathbb{R}$ or only a bijection exists between the two?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is not really a question, it’s just I want to have a confirmation the two are not exactly equal but instead a bijection exists between them.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: How do you mean with $\mathbb R^1$? If you mean the set of "$1$-tuples" of real numbers, then how do you *precisely* define a $1$-tuple? If you define a $1$-tuple $(a)$ as just $a$ (which, I would say, is a fine definition), then they are equal. Otherwise, probably not.

Comment: Used the wrong word...thanks for pointing out!

Comment: I’m going to define a 1-tuple as a function from $\{ \emptyset \}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the map $x\mapsto(x)$ is ***so*** canonical, it ends up being really a matter of definition.

In a strict sense, $\Bbb R^1$ is the set of all functions from $\{\varnothing\}$ into $\Bbb R$, in which case $\Bbb R$ is *not* the same set as $\Bbb R^1$.

However, in less strict contexts one can see definitions which go along these lines, $A^1=A$ and $A^{n+1}=A^n\times A$. In that case, $\Bbb R^1$ is by definition $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks as usual Asaf! Is there a way to start the recursive definition from $\mathbb{R}^{0}$ or I have to define $\mathbb{R}^{0}$ to be $\{\emptyset\}$ at the beginning? I’m obviously pointing to your second definition here.

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb R^0$ should be $\{\varnothing\}$, and you can use that as your base. In that case $\Bbb R^1$ is $\{(\varnothing, r) \mid r\in\Bbb R\}$.